# how to make password input box get focus in login screen (juno)

Tags: greeter

in juno have to mouse click in password input box (fresh OS setup), in Loki the box get focus automatically after OS start.

is there any option I can use? thanks.

Comment: It's a known (and annoying) issue - there is a bug raised for it, you can check the progress here: https://github.com/elementary/greeter/issues/144