# How to get cursor autofocus on login screen?

Tags: settings, keyboard, elementary-project

Is there a way to get the cursor to autofocus on login screen? Currently I have to use the mouse to get the cursor to the login screen in order to enter the password. I would like to be able to just enter my password without having to use mouse to get cursor to password field.

Comment: This question has already been asked:
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16621/how-to-make-password-input-box-get-focus-in-login-screen-juno It's a known bug.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the update. I was not aware. Cheers

Comment: In case anyone else wants to track the actual bug in github, here is the link: https://github.com/elementary/greeter/issues/144